# Amalgamate A6 size sheets print on A4 size page

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

**Scenario:** My Excel file has about 120 sheets. I have used 1 page per sheet. Size of the page is A6. So, I have 120 A6 pages on the entire workbook.

**What I need to be done:** I want to make a single sheet of A6 page size each, which contains all the A6 sheets in the entire workbook. Then I need to print it on A4 size pages (4 x A6 pages per sheet).

**Problem:** Following code collects all the sheets into one single sheet. But the issue is it collects A6 pages to a "Letter" size page. So, when I the click print preview it shows 20 small pages in one A4 sheet. When I select A4 it should display only 4 pages per sheet (since, A4 =4 X A6). But why this is showing 20 pages. It prints very small 20 pages on A4 instead of 4 pages. This is not a printer setting or page setup issue, but the code it self generate such a sheet.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim wshTemp As Worksheet, wsh As Worksheet
Dim rngArr() As Range, c As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

ReDim rngArr(1 To 1)
For Each wsh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    i = i + 1
    If i > 1 Then   ' resize array
        ReDim Preserve rngArr(1 To i)
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    Set c = wsh.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
    If Err = 0 Then
        On Error GoTo 0

        'Prevent empty rows
        Do While Application.CountA(c.EntireRow) = 0 _
          And c.EntireRow.Row > 1
            Set c = c.Offset(-1, 0)
        Loop

        Set rngArr(i) = wsh.Range(wsh.Range("A1"), c)
    End If
Next wsh

'Add temp.Worksheet
Set wshTemp = Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))

On Error Resume Next
With wshTemp
    For i = 1 To UBound(rngArr)
        If i = 1 Then
            Set c = .Range("A1")
        Else
            Set c = _
              ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
            Set c = c.Offset(2, 0).End(xlToLeft)  'Skip one row
        End If

        'Copy-paste range (prevent empty range)
        If Application.CountA(rngArr(i)) > 0 Then
            rngArr(i).Copy c
        End If
    Next i
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Application.CutCopyMode = False ' prevent marquies

With ActiveSheet.PageSetup     'Fit to 1 page
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 1

End With

'Preview New Sheet
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintPreview

'Print Desired Number of Copies
i = InputBox("Print how many copies?", "ExcelTips", 1)
If IsNumeric(i) Then
    If i > 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.PrintOut Copies:=i
    End If
End If

'Delete temp.Worksheet?
If MsgBox("Delete the temporary worksheet?", _
  vbYesNo, "ExcelTips") = vbYes Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wshTemp.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: With ActiveSheet.PageSetup     'Fit to 1 page
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 1    I believe that this is your problem. Try changing to different value. If you will see change you need to come up with way to divide worksheet.count by 4 and split them evenly or make Wide = 1, tall = count/4

Comment: @Claudius it doesn't do anything

Comment: I mean it will look the same, put does print preview look any different? This part of the code tells excel to fit  whole worksheet on single print page

Comment: @Claudius it doesn't do any change on the print preview too .. I think, when the code copy the pages it pastes it to a "Letter" sized page. if it copy it to a A6 Sized page, the problem will be solved that I will be able to select 4 pages on the print preview. IDK, I understand little about macro.

Comment: according to this it is your zoom http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/542463-visual-basic-applications-set-selected-print-area-fit-1-page-then-check-zoom-visibility.html

Comment: Why not print each worksheet in a loop, assuming each one is specified to needed setting and print area? No need to move all in one tab.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup     'Fit to 1 page
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 1

End With
```

to

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup     'Fit to 1 page
    .Zoom = 100
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 1

End With
```

Comment: with this change, now it shows 2 pages in the print preview. The data and text are out of the page area of the newly created sheet by macro. The code is copying and pasting the data to a letter sized pages. That's the issue. Is there any page size to set in that code. Or some code like this '.PageSize = A6' or something.